# Saving XML File from URL on my Server

Tags: php, xml, cron

I am able to put the following url in any browser and the xml appears after a few seconds...
   ftp://USER:PASSWORD@aphrodite.WEBSITE.net/exports/xml/products.xml

I tried the following code in a php file so I can run a cron daily at midnight and for it to save the xml file on my server. There is a xml file being saved in my data directory but it is blank. Any ideas?

```
<?php 
$content =     file_get_contents('ftp://USER:PASSWORD@aphrodite.WEBSITE.net/exports/xml/products.xml');
file_put_contents('./data/products.xml', $xml);
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php 
$xml = file_get_contents('ftp://USER:PASSWORD@aphrodite.WEBSITE.net/exports/xml/products.xml');
file_put_contents('./data/products.xml', $xml);
?>
```

Your `$content` is not used in the **file_put_contents** method call so you are not writing anything to the file. I changed the code so that the data gets written to the file.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing wrong with your code since `file_get_contents` almost supports all the protocols, But you may need to change `$xml` to `$content` because as I see `$xml` variable does not exists in your code.